# Django asynchronous requests

Tags: django, asynchronous, celery

Does Django have something similar to ASP.NET MVC's [Asynchronous Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

I have some requests that will be handled by celery workers, but won't take a long time (a few seconds). I want the clients to get the response after the worker is done. I can have my view function wait for the task to complete, but I'm worried it will put too much burden on the webserver.

Clarification:

Here's the flow I can have today

```
def my_view(request):
    async = my_task.delay(params)
    result = async.get()
    return my_response(result)
```

`async.get()` can take a few seconds - not too long so that the client can't wait for the HTTP response to get back.

This code might put unnecessary strain on the server. What ASP.NET MVC's `AsynchronousController` provides, is the ability to break this function in two, something similar to this:

```
def my_view(request):
    async = my_task.delay(params)
    return DelayedResponse(async, lambda result=>my_response(result))
```

This releases the webserver to handle other requests until the async operation is done. Once it done, it will execute the lambda expression on the result, giving back the response.

Answer (score 2):

1. Instead of waiting for request to complete, you can return status "In progress" an then send one more request to check if status has changed. Since you're doing pure lookups, the response will be very fast and won't put much burden on your web server.
2. You can outsource this specific view/feature to Tornado web server which is designed for async callback. The rest of the site may continue to run on django.
3. Most likely the solution should be not technical, but in UI/UX area. If something takes long, it's ok to notify user about it if notification is clear.

Comment: As for 1 and 3 - I don't want to have the client send another request. It is still short enough to be acceptable by the end-users.

Comment: @zmbq You don't have many options on the web. Either you do `polling`, `long polling` or `websockets`. If you are 100% sure it can be done in one request/response cycle you shouldn't use celery. If you do use it, pick any of the 3 methods I mentioned. ASP.NET's Async Controller, I suspect, it justs hides the above details.

Comment: What ASP.NET's async controller does, is free a thread on the webserver while the asynchronous operation takes place. The webserver's thread is free to handle another request. Once the asynchronous task is complete, the webserver assigns it to one of the running threads and continues its processing. It has nothing to do with the *client* polling, using websockets, or something else.

Comment: @zmbq More or less this is what every async server does. You forgot the most important detail - how does the client gets updated? How does it get the response? Does it break the laws of physics or http? P.S. Please don't forget the `@` symbol when replying to someone in order for him to be notified.

Comment: @zmbq I just read up on ASP.NET async controller. What it does has nothing to do with the client connection. The http connection remains synchronous. You don't need something like this in pre-fork multiworker environments like gunicorn or uwsgi(which is what django mostly uses). What you have to do in this case is simply decide on the number of workers based on your system and workload. For everything else that may exceed the request/response time, just use celery.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something only when the task completes. You would want to look into something called `chain()`. You can bind celery tasks in chain:

```
    chain = first_function.s(set) | second_Function.s(do)

    chain()
```

These two functions `first_function and second_function` will both are celery functions. The second_function is executed only when first_function finishes its execution.

Comment: For more information: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html?highlight=chain#celery.chain

Comment: I don't want to chain task. I'll clarify.